# Struts2 if tag not evaluating

Tags: jsp, if-statement, struts2, iterator, ognl

I have this code that iterates through a certain collection of objects, I want to perform type checking (or `instanceof`) operator on each element. however on my `<s:if>`, it seems to be not evaluating. What am I missing?

```
<s:iterator value = "myQuestions" var = "q"  status="key">

        <s:checkbox name="myQuestions[%{#key.index}].chosen" />
        <s:property value = "%{myQuestions[#key.index].question}"/> 

    <s:if test ="%{myQuestions[#key.index].getClass().simpleName} == 'Question'" > 
            THIS IS A QUESTION.
    </s:if> 


</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Which Java version are you running in your application server? According to the API, `getSimpleName` requires Java 1.5 or greater

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend against using class type as a view-layer functionality switch. Surely you can do this in a cleaner, less-fragile way.

Comment: @DaveNewton what do you have in mind?

Comment: @user962206 Without knowing more, I don't know. Storing different object types in a single list is very often a smell. What are you differentiating them from? Answers? A question should have answers--a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

a better way to achieve the functionality of if loop would be to write one public function on the Action layer that returns a string value(of the class name) and takes Question type as an argument. Some related example could be like this

```
public String getClassName(Ouestion question){
  if(question instanceof SomeDerivedQuestion){
    return "someDerivedQuestion";
  }
  //other code comes below
}
```

Now in the JSP you can do something like this

```
<s:if test="%{getClassName(myQuestions[#key.index]).equals('someDerivedQuestion')}> 
  THIS IS A DERIVED QUESTION.
</s:if>
```

JSP is better left to handle the presentation part of the application and cover the required coding on the Java Server Side